# Convergence of the series $\sum \frac{(-1)^{\sqrt{n}}}{n}.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm looking for some help to show that:

$$\sum {(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor}\over n} < \infty$$

Comment: I'm a little confused. The [tag:real-analysis] tag and $<$ sign seem to imply you're working in $\mathbb R$, but generally $(-21)^{\sqrt n}$ will not be real.

Comment: Can be $(-1)^n/\sqrt n$?

Comment: he probably means he's taking the floor function of $\sqrt{n}$, i.e. the biggest integer smaller or equal to that. in this case OP might want to try to use Leibniz's criterion - for a slightly different, suitably chosen series

Comment: It doesn't appear that there is any type of floor function in the power on the test I am looking at, but there are square brackets around it. It must be a typo since this is in fact a real analysis exam.

Comment: Edited. I still don't see the series that I should be comparing this to.

Comment: The square brackets are crucial. They probably refer to the floor function (use `\lfloor` and `\rfloor`).

Comment: Well, the exam this comes from has no floor brackets! Lazy writing.

Comment: Why "lazy"? They probably use simple brackets $[$ and $]$ for floor brackets $\lfloor$ and $\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clarification, it seems that the goal is to prove that the sequence $(S_n)$ converges, where, for every $n\geqslant1$,
$$
S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor k\rfloor}}k.
$$
To do so, consider, for every $n\geqslant1$,
$$
T_n=\sum_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1}\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor k\rfloor}}k=(-1)^n\sum_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1}\frac1k.
$$
For every $n$,
$$
|T_n|\leqslant\sum_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1}\frac1{n^2}=\frac{2n+1}{n^2}\leqslant\frac3n,
$$
hence $T_n\to0$. Furthermore, the signs of the entries $T_n$ alternate hence, if the sequence $|T_n|$ is noninceasing, the series
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant1}T_n
$$
is an alternating series and, as such, its sums converge to some limit $\ell$. For every $n$, there exists some $k$ such that $k^2\leqslant n\lt (k+1)^2$ hence
$$
\sum_{i=1}^kT_i\leqslant S_n\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}T_i\quad\text{or}\quad\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}T_i\leqslant S_n\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^{k}T_i,
$$
depending on the parity of $k$. This proves that $S_n\to\ell$.

To conclude, it remains to show that indeed $|T_{n+1}|\leqslant|T_n|$ for every $n$. Can you do that?

Comment: I can. Thanks alot!